# sorted(file.read().split()) Not giving sorted results

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is not working for Numbers. Example,

I have values like

```
[99,37,74,98,223,189]
```

using the below command, output we get is

```
[189,223,37,74,98,99]
```

But actual output expected is

```
[37,74,98,99,189,223]
```

Code:

```
word_list = sorted(fh.read().split())
```

Comment: Doesn't your actual output contain quotation marks?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your array consists of stringified numbers. Convert into integer and then sort.

Comment: Obviously, since `fh.read().split()` returns a list of strings.

Comment: Perhaps you should add how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

*How about*

```
values = [99, 37, 74, 98, 223, 189]
values = [int(i) for i in values]
print(sorted(values))
```

---

> [37, 74, 98, 99, 189, 223]

Comment: This isn't helpful, since he's getting the numbers from a file, not entering them in the script.

Answer (score 0):

You are sorting the string representations of the numbers rather than the numbers themselves, so it is sorting by the first character of the text rather than by the size of the number it represents. ie, `1234` will be sorted before `23` because the `1` is less than the `2`.
To sort numerically in-line, you could use: `sorted([int(num) for num in file.read().split()])`. To make your code more readable, you could split this up into multiple lines:

```py
texts=file.read().split()
numbers=[int(num) for num in texts]
sorted_numbers=sorted(numbers)
```

Comment: "sorted([int(num) for num in file.read().split()])" This works, as a general practice in python, as we're opening for loop, do we need to close this?

Is this a right way to program?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your comment. List comprehensions are a commonly used feature of python, yes; though it does impair readability, hence why I split it into multiple lines also. Does this clarify my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this:

```py
values = '99 37 74 98 223 189'.split()
results = sorted(map(int, values))
```

In this way, you are applying the function `int` to every value of `values`

Comment: the author is asking for how to get sorted numbers _out of a file,_ so this doesnt directly answer their question

Comment: @ZaeZoxol there is no difference. The author problem is about "how to convert string to int"

Comment: The name of the question says `file.read()`, their issue is the distinction that when reading numbers from a file, they are strings and not integers/floats. Your answer does not include reading from a file, which is a minor fix, but I was unsure if editing your post to include it would qualify as "respecting original author"

Comment: @ZaeZoxol it's the same solution, the OP has no problem reading from a file.